# Why half of my icon disappears in Positioned widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is the widget where I get this error

```
Card(
      child: Container(
          height: 250,
          width: 200,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Stack(children: [
                Image(image: NetworkImage(user!.photoUrl)),
                Positioned(
                  child: CircleAvatar(child: Icon(Icons.add)),
                  left: 40,
                  top: 100,
               
                )
              ])
            ],
          ))),
```

Here is a screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYoJe.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to increase height of Container (parent of Column/Stack). **250px** is maybe too small to display avatar & icon "add". The question is, how big is your `CircleAvatar(child: Icon(Icons.add))`? Then plus 100px (top-padding) and calculate the right height.

**Edit**: By the way, you can remove `Column` wrapping `Stack`, it is not neccessary.

Comment: As you said I  try to do it but I think it depends on image height. Anyways thank you.